# gcloud run that requires large databse

Tags: gcloud

i hope this is the right place to ask this. So what i want to do is perform a sequence search against a large database and create an API for this. I expect that this service will be accessed VERY rarely, as such I though about gcloud run, because this only bills me for each use case (and i dont use a lot). I already have a docker container configured that does what i expect it to, however I have an issue with the data thats required. I need a Database thats roughly 100 GB large. Is there a way to access this in glcoud run?

What would be the optimal way for me to get there? I think downlading 100GB of data every time a request is made is a waste. Maybe I could fetch a zip file from a storage bucket and inflate it in the run instance? But I am not sure if there is even that much space available.

Thank you

Comment: Google Cloud Run supports accessing most types of databases. What is the problem that you have? As written, your question is too broad and does not present a problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simpler way to do this is to rip the weight of the Cloud Run shoulders.

I'm assuming it is some sort of structured data (json, csv, etc) - if it really is it is simpler to import this data into BigQuery and make your Cloud Run service to query against BQ.

This way your API will answer way faster, you will save costs from running Cloud Run with very large instances to load into memory part of those 100gigs as also you will separate your architecture in layers (ie. an application layer and a data layer).